Connected Apps and Managed package and Tokens
Let me explain what I am trying to build. I am developing an LWC component that displays data from a custom object stored in another Salesforce org. To ensure that the target org is connected, users will be asked to enter an endpoint URL. After this, a new window should open where the user will be prompted enter user credentials. Upon successful authentication and authorization, I plan to store details like Access_Token__c, Refresh_Token__c, Instance_URL__c, and Org_ID__c in a custom object in the source org. Once the target org is connected successfully, then I can retrieve data from target org and display in the source org, in a table format. If everything works fine, this entire setup needs to be packaged.
Now, I believe we also need to create a connected app in the target org. So my questions are:

Can I package a connected app in a managed package? From some of the posts I’ve seen on StackExchange, it seems like it can be done. However, there are so many considerations and limitations that I’m confused about whether, for my use case, I can package it or not. The example presented above is a simplified version of what I am trying to do, but yes it will definitely be installed in multiple orgs.
In most of the apps out there, is it the right approach to store tokens in a custom object, or a protected custom setting? I did some research to see if I could create a named credential using Apex, but it looks like this is not possible. If it were possible, I guess there would be no need to create a custom object.


I believe you can package a connected app. but the direction of communication between orgs places a form of twist. for your use case which seems like a many to many org connection , it appears you may need a way to get the client secret for each target org instance per source org. because while the client ID is always included in the metadata file for the connected app, i am of the opinion that the client secret is generated per org (not too sure about this).
I dont have a verdict on whether it is an entirely bad idea to store tokens in a custom object. But i think the determining factors would be whether you are able to define restrictions to how accessible the object is, especially from the UI.
